# Was "Fukai Mori" only used in the Inuyasha soundtrack?

Tags: music, naruto, inuyasha

I know this song, and I remember it being part of the Naruto OST. But when I search about "Fukai Mori" in YouTube, it shows that it was part of the OST for the *Inuyasha* anime.

Am I remembering wrong? Was "Fukai Mori" only used in the *Inuyasha* soundtrack, or was it used in *Naruto* as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can find (including some googling in Japanese that I admit I'm not that strong in), Fukai Mori only appears in conjunction with Naruto as an AMV (a fan-made Anime Music Video), never on any official Naruto soundtrack of any kind.

In fact, Do As Infinity don't seem to have had a song appear in connection with Naruto anywhere despite their fairly significant back catalogue.

So, the most likely answer is that you made a false association, possibly because one of the Naruto songs sounded a bit like Fukai Mori, or because you saw the AMV or something like it.

Comment: Maybe thats why i think it was naruto ost. Because it sound really familiar eventhough i never really watch inuyasha, and thats why im really confused.
Thanks for your answer btw

Answer (score 0):

It may also sound familiar to you because of the song "Wind" by Akeboshi that was used as one of Naruto's ending themes. It features a similar sounding flute.